# C# lock single line (if statement)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, if-statement, locking

Is this code locking only on `if` statement, or for both lines of code?

```
lock (LockObject)
    if (instance == null)
        instance = Instance();
```

Comment: Currently it wouldn't even compile because of the missing semicolon.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `Lazy<T>` which shows your intent more clearly and it's thread safe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`lock` locks an entire block. Since it's not followed by curly braces (`{}`), it locks an implicit block - the `if` statement. Here, the same logic applies - `if` executes a block if the condition is met. Since it is also not followed by curly braces, it implicitly has a block that contains a single statement. In other words, the given code is equivalent to:

```
lock (LockObject) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = Instance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`if` statement can't be executed alone, it needs block after it for the `true`-case of expression, so, as @Mureinik already said, `lock` locks your entire initialization block. You can even write it like this:

```
lock (LockObject) if (instance == null) instance = Instance();
```

However, this is not recommended to write your code without curly braces in such cases as it is very confusing and hard to debug. Also note that `lock` statement is a syntax sugar for [`Monitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) class usage, and your code is compiled into this:

```
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(LockObject);
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = Instance();
    }
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(LockObject);
}
```

And I want to note that for **initialization logic** you can use a [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) class, which is thread-safe, and uses not so heavy constructures as `Monitor`, and can perform faster than your code. Code will be like this:

```
// field in class
Lazy<Instance> lazyInstance = new Lazy<Instance>(() => Instance());

//usage in code
var instanceValue = lazyInstance.Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Lock is translated by the C# compiler to `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`. This C# code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    lock (LockObject)
        if (instance == null)
            instance = Instance();
    Console.WriteLine(instance == null);
}
```

gives the IL code below, which clearly shows that `Monitor.Exit` (L_0036) is called after `instance` is assigned (L_0026).

Both lines of code are locked.

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .maxstack 2
  .locals init (
    [0] bool flag,
    [1] object obj2,
    [2] bool flag2)
  L_0000: nop
  L_0001: ldc.i4.0
  L_0002: stloc.0
  L_0003: ldsfld object TestLock.Program::LockObject
  L_0008: dup
  L_0009: stloc.1
  L_000a: ldloca.s flag
  L_000c: call void [mscorlib]System.Threading.Monitor::Enter(object, bool&)
  L_0011: nop
  L_0012: ldsfld object TestLock.Program::instance
  L_0017: ldnull
  L_0018: ceq
  L_001a: ldc.i4.0
  L_001b: ceq
  L_001d: stloc.2
  L_001e: ldloc.2
  L_001f: brtrue.s L_002b
  L_0021: call object TestLock.Program::Instance()
  L_0026: stsfld object TestLock.Program::instance
  L_002b: leave.s L_003d
  L_002d: ldloc.0
  L_002e: ldc.i4.0
  L_002f: ceq
  L_0031: stloc.2
  L_0032: ldloc.2
  L_0033: brtrue.s L_003c
  L_0035: ldloc.1
  L_0036: call void [mscorlib]System.Threading.Monitor::Exit(object)
  L_003b: nop
  L_003c: endfinally
  L_003d: nop
  L_003e: ldsfld object TestLock.Program::instance
  L_0043: ldnull
  L_0044: ceq
  L_0046: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(bool)
  L_004b: nop
  L_004c: ret
  .try L_0003 to L_002d finally handler L_002d to L_003d
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's locking all of the code. Here `{` and `}` for `if` are just omitted.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement includes a statement for the "then" case. So the lock applies to both lines.

A simple rule of thumb is: if there's a `{` it applies until the matching `}`, otherwise it applies until the first `;`. That does not cover *all* situations, but certainly the most common ones.

Answer (score 0):

It is locking the whole statement. Consider the following example:

```
 lock (LockObject)
 {
     if (instance == null) {
 }
```

If it is only locking the `if` condition when using braces, then it will result to compiler error since it is not properly arranged/matched.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is locking both lines of code.

Lock on LockObject won't be released until if statement has finished execution. It means, if your condition in line 2 is true then it's going to execute line 3 before releasing the lock in line 1

Hope that helps :)